# How to create interface memebers automatically when implementing an interface

Tags: visual-studio-2012, interface

How to create interface memebers automatically when implementing an interface? I have found different solutions on the web, but none of them work for VB.net in Visual Studio 2012.

The solutions I have tested includes (1) hitting ENTER directly after writing the "implements ISomeInterface" (2) cliking on the "ISomeInterface" and pressing "CTRL + .". None of them worked.

Comment: Are you talking about the default implementation that Visual Studio automatically creates for interfaces?

Comment: @taegost I am just talking about creating the methods signatures inside of the class that you are implementing this interface.

Comment: wich version of VS2012 do you have?

Comment: @rudym Visual Studio Premium 2012 - Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4

Comment: (1) is the way it works in VB.NET and VS2012.  You left no breadcrumbs to guess why it doesn't work for you.  In case it needs to be said, the interface does have to have some members.

Comment: @HansPassant After you said that, I restarted my laptop and when I opened VS2012 again it worked like as described in my attempt (1). I guess it might have been some sort of bug in VS.